# IServiceLocator.GetInstance<TService>() is not working

Tags: linq, c#-3.0, structuremap

We have an extension method to register the service as shown below
we are saying return me the out of proc instance only if the key is remote host name. in detail we expected to receive  in proc instance for all three calls mentioned below

IStudyService studyService = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance(Stentor.Server.ServerInfo.HostName)

IStudyService studyService2 = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance("localhost");

IStudyService studyService3 = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance()
The first two calls are working as expected but when we go with empty key for third call highlighted one  we are getting out of  proc instead the in proc

we have condition mentioned like if the requested key empty or localhost or hostanme return ThenIt.Is.Type();

but for (String.IsNullOrEmpty(context.RequestedName) this condition is not wokring and the below code is getting executed

Can you please suggest what's wrong in this code or how the context has to be registered when the empty key needs to be processed

Thanks & regards

Sukumar

Answer (score 0):

Code for registration

```
return (String.IsNullOrEmpty(context.RequestedName) ||
              context.RequestedName.Equals("localhost", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ||
              context.RequestedName.Equals(ServerInfo.HostName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
```